# Avoiding internal threads in a shared object

Tags: c, linux, unix, asynchronous, shared-libraries

We have a product that loads a shared object which monitors internal function invocations inside a random process (Let's call it myDb) using 'dll injection' and 'instrumentation' techniques.

Currently, our shared object has an internal thread that recv() messages from our main process which is an external entity.

It all works well until myDb fork()s and creates an identical child process which doesn't end up with execve(). This identical child process main thread starts in the context of the parent thread that called fork(), and all the other parent's threads are no longer exist in the child. This might corrupt our shared object internal state because our internal thread can disappear at any point of execution (See more about mixing threads with forks in http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them).

MyDb can use forks without asking us, and so, correct me if I am wrong, it seems that we have no alternative but make our code works without internal threads.

The only option I can think about is asynchronous i/o.
According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html, notification from asynchronous routines are done using sigevent. sigevent can use SIGEV_SIGNAL in order to receive notifications using signals or by using SIGEV_THREAD which according to the man page uses an actual threads underneath.
And so, it seems to me that the only option we have is to use asynchronous i/o with the SIGEV_SIGNAL option. But this has many limitations too, because handling the messages inside a signal handler is dangerous because one can only call async-signal-safe functions.

I will be glad to here any suggestions to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: *MyDb can use forks without asking us, and so, correct me if I am wrong, it seems that we have no alternative but make our code works without internal threads.*  But if you do that, how will your code know if it's the original parent or the forked child process?  Whatever state you're in will be snapshotted and replicated in the child, perhaps in an inconsistent state if you're in the middle of a transaction.  Async IO isn't going to fix that, and might even make things worse - how will the child handle what appears to be scheduled IO operations that really belong to the parent?

Comment: You are right. That is why we also intercept the fork() calls. I also came across with the pthread_atfork() that in theory can help me synchronize the fork() and avoid the corruption, but I prefer another method if possible.

Comment: May I offer an alternative solution? Don't inject code in random other processes. I've had to spend quite a bit of time debugging "our" software when another "helpful" process injected itself into random other processes including ours. So it wasn't our code that crashed, even though we thought of it as "our" process. Injection is only OK if the injector and the victim are written by the same organization, ideally by the same team, so they can be tested in conjunction.

Comment: We obviously don't do this for fun - It is a security product. Don't worry, the first thing the vendors do when they see our code mapped in there memory space is to disable our product.

Comment: You can use a ptracer process that does [`ptrace(PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK, ...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) (after your own injected thread allows the tracing of the process) to catch all `fork()` calls, so that you can make the new child "execute" an also injected function to recreate the watcher thread (via register manipulation; needs a pre-prepared single-use "stack"). Low overhead, high complexity; can be made secure (although most devs, including security sensitive software devs, won't bother).

Comment: Nice approach even though as you said it will be pretty complex, and will also require the process to be traced it's entire lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found is to register handlers using the `pthread_atfork()`.
This API can help to synchronize the `fork()` with the other threads that resides in the process to avoid memory inconsistency.

More in https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_atfork

Unfortunately, it is not always easy to solve this using the `pthread_atfork()` because each one of the process' threads must cooperate, which is a strict assumption. In addition to that, it kind of broke our design.

We decided to change our attitude and to use **jobs** instead of **threads**. I'll explain:

Usually, when creating threads, they all block most of the time on some call (`read()`, `sleep()`, etc...), in those cases the threadness is not really needed, it might makes more sense to use jobs instead.

We developed a JobScheduler() class which dispatches jobs to the ones that are registered to it (Per timeout, fd ready read, etc..). 
Now, in this class we defined a fork-safe-zone which is the only one we allow a fork to happen, and if a fork occurs during an ongoing job, the fork will be delayed until the job is over.
This induce a limitation that job execution must be relatively fast and by no means block the thread.

This fork-safe-zone enabled us to enforce consistency of the memory space in the child process (using the `pthread_atfork()`), in addition, we can also re-create this worker thread in the child-post-fork callback, which will make the fork limitations invisible.